# In a function variables isn't getting affected/changed by the changes made to them

Tags: javascript, function, cypress

in my code, I'm going through movies on a movie page and checking their rate in order to find the best-rated movie and return it but the function is returning the variables that I defined without any changes - "","0"

**the code:**

```
 bestRatedFanFav() {
        let baseNumber = 0;
        let max = "0";
        let movieName = "";

        for (let index = 0; index < 2; index++) {
             cy.get(".FoldSplitterGrid__StyledSubGrid-tz9qri-0").eq(baseNumber).children().its('length').then(length => {
                for (let index = 0; index < (length - 11); index++) {
                    cy.get(".FoldSplitterGrid__StyledSubGrid-tz9qri-0").eq(baseNumber).children().eq(index).as('el');
                    cy.get('@el').should('exist', { timeout: 10000 }).click({ froce : true });
                    cy.url().should('contain', 'title');
                    cy.get('.AggregateRatingButton__RatingScore-sc-1ll29m0-1.iTLWoV').eq(0).invoke('text').then(($rate) => {
                    cy.log("$rate.toString() : " + $rate.toString());
                        if ($rate.toString() > max) {
                             cy.get("[data-testid=hero-title-block__title]").invoke('text').then(($movie) => {
                                movieName = $movie;
                                cy.log("movieName : " + movieName)
                            });
                            max = $rate.toString() ;
                            cy.log("current max : " + max)
                        }
                    });
                    cy.go(-1);
                    cy.url().should('contain', 'fan-favorites', { timeout: 10000 });
                }

                baseNumber++;
            });       
        } 
        cy.log("final MOVIE NAME : " + movieName);
        cy.log("final max : " + max);
            return max;
    }
```

Comment: Could it be that cy.get isn't executed instantly? The docs say that cy.get can timeout [link](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get). Does the console display moveName : some movie?

Comment: Check out this blog post from Filip Hric about Cypress and Variables -- Don't have a great solution for your problem, but I think it highlights why your variables aren't behaving as expected -- https://filiphric.com/cypress-basics-variables